# I am trying to add a static option to a dynamic drop down field in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an in house web based license tracking application for my small business. The web filter contains a dynamic drop down box that populates based on the data in a certain field within the database.

It works great and is functional now, but I would like to add some functionality to it.

Currenty there are two drop down boxes, one for department and one for software. The way it works is, you set those two filter, and it will output a table with all the records that match BOTH criteria. This makes it easy to see all software licenses of a particular application that each department has ordered and had installed.

What I have started doing, is using this to also track uninstalled, or available licenses to cut software costs, and re-use more. What I would like to do is add a static ALL option to each of the fields so it will select all departments that match the selected software, or show all the software that matches a particular department, and in some rare cases set both to all so it displays all software from all departments.

Here is the code that I currently have in place and is functioning properly...

```
<?php

 echo "<p><a href='view.php'>View All</a> | <a href='un_view.php'>View Uninstalled</a> | <a href='view_paginated.php?page=1'>View Printable Version</a></p>";
 echo "<br>";

 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 
<p><strong>Filter Options</strong></P>
 <?php    
 $sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT dept FROM sw_lic";
 $sql3 = "SELECT DISTINCT sw_name FROM sw_lic WHERE sw_name != ''";
 $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
 $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
 ?>
       <form action="filter_view.php" method="POST">
           <p><select name="dept">
<?php
       while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
       {
       echo "<option name='dept' value=$nt[dept]>$nt[dept]</option>";
       }
?>
       </select>
       <select name="sw_name">
<?php
       while($st=mysql_fetch_array($result3))
       {
       echo "<option name='sw_name' value='$st[sw_name]'>$st[sw_name]</option>";
       }
?>
       </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 <?php 
 }




 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
 $sysname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sysname']));
 $dept = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['dept']));
 $sw_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sw_name']));
 $sw_ver = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sw_ver']));
 $origin = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['origin']));
 $sw_key = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sw_key']));

 // check to make sure all fields are entered
 if ($username == '' || $dept == '' || $sw_name == '' || $sw_ver == '' || $origin == '' || $sw_key == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, display the form again
 renderForm($username, $sysname, $dept, $sw_name, $sw_ver, $origin, $sw_key, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT sw_lic SET username='$username', sysname='$sysname', dept='$dept', sw_name='$sw_name', sw_ver='$sw_ver', origin='$origin', sw_key='$sw_key'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: view.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
 {
 renderForm('','','');
 }
?>
```

If anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it. If anymore details are required please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Just add an option for "all" and then dynamically build your query depending on this value.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a static option value like this:

```
<p><select name="dept">
    <option value="_all_">All</option>
<?php
       while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
       {
       echo "<option name='dept' value=$nt[dept]>$nt[dept]</option>";
       }
?>
       </select>
</p>
```

And then modify your query accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a shot and get back to you with the results.

Comment: Ok, I am apparenlty butchering this script. I have tried your explanation, and while it added the All option to the menu I am confused on what needs to be done to pass a wildcard to my filtered view page.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "wildcard". Probably you you'll need to alter your SQL query in the filtered view page to display display `sw_lic` results that have `dept == '_all_'` too. (e.g. add `OR dept == '_all_'` to your SQL statement)